# wp_posts table post_status update with processing instead of wc-processing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am working for a payment gateway I am writing bellow code

```php
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);   
if($data && $data->status == "ACCEPTED")
{
     wc_maybe_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);
     $order -> update_status('Processing');
     $order -> payment_complete();
```

I notice the wp_posts table post_status updated with processing while I am updating status from the web panel GUI it updated with wc-processing

[image: Image 1]

In the above image id **79** updated from the panel and **80** updated programmatically

---

In both case wp_wc_order_stats updated with wc-processing

[image]

When the post_status updated with processing it's not displayed in the order list in the panel

[image]

I am not sure is it a bug or I am making any mistakes but this works for an earlier version.

- My current **wp version 5.3.2**
- My current  **wc version 4.0.1**

Comment: $order -> update_status('Processing');
 VS.      $order -> update_status('processing');